# Where is the datepicker in material ui next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am try use `next` branch of material ui https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/next. Because i want use `layout` component. But i can not find `DatePicker` component! 
How use `DatePicker` in `next` branch?

```
import {DatePicker} from 'material-ui'
```

`WARNING in ./app/Resources/js/components/FormConstructor/Field.js
208:47-57 "export 'DatePicker' was not found in 'material-ui'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment to write this answer (2017-06-12) it's still not supported. See https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/getting-started/supported-components

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I am in the same boat. And I dearly miss the DatePicker from the stable release of material-ui (dated 10/04/2018). I too upgraded to the @next, at the moment at v1.0.0-beta.41 and reached the state of shock to not have found the elegant DatePicker.

This is what I have noticed and now changing to -

> https://material-ui-next.com/demos/pickers/

It has a date picker, which is actually based out of the TextField component having the type set to "date".
Copying as is -

> ```
>   <TextField
>     id="date"
>     label="Birthday"
>     type="date"
>     defaultValue="2017-05-24"
>     className={classes.textField}
>     InputLabelProps={{
>       shrink: true,
>     }}
>   />
> ```

A small suggestion would be to check if the path exists under the local node_modules. You can also quickly check the component catalogue (at https://material-ui-next.com/) for the version you are using.

Hope this helps.

Comment: At least as of now, Material-UI Next (including the demo at https://material-ui-next.com/demos/pickers/) just wraps the browser's native datepicker, or more specifically, `<input type="date">`, which has limited [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the native controls you can use the [Mobiscroll Calendar](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/react/calendar) and [Date picker](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/react/datetime).
Pretty customizable and comes with material styling that fits well with the general look & feel.

### Calendar component

[image: Calendar component]

### Date picker component

[image: Date picker]

---

*Full disclosure: this is a commercial component, and I am one of the makers, just though it could help someone looking for a solution.*

Answer (score -1):

Import as DatePickers, TimePickers, DateAndTimePickers in latest material-ui version V1.0.0-beta.26.

Eg:

```
import {DatePickers, TimePickers, DateAndTimePickers} from 'material-ui';
```

Importing Datepicker as like below is no more valid in latest version.

Eg:

```
import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [here](https://github.com/chingyawhao/material-ui-next-datepicker) where I did an example of creating a datepicker using material-ui (next branch)

You can either import the component or just check out the source code to learn how to create a datepicker on your own

Answer (score -4):

use this
`import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker';`

also visit this [link](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker) for completed details about material-ui date-picker.
Don't forget to install material-ui i.e  **npm install --save material-ui**

sample code below

```
const DatePickerExampleSimple = () => (
  <div>
    <DatePicker hintText="Portrait Dialog" />
    <DatePicker hintText="Landscape Dialog" mode="landscape" />
    <DatePicker hintText="Dialog Disabled" disabled={true} />
  </div>
);

export default DatePickerExampleSimple;
```

Comment: But how? I can not find references on DatePicker in source code!

Comment: This work! But how? I can not find references on DatePicker in source code in repository `material-ui`!

Comment: you have imported import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker'; so you can use anywhere <DatePicker> in that page

Comment: My question is about something else. I can not understand how work import if component miss in source code material -ui

Comment: when we use " npm install --save material-ui " it is installed in our pkg folder that is node_modules then we can use anywhere in our app

Comment: No. I made a mistake. This not work. Warning hide, but error occuired:
ERROR in ./app/Resources/js/components/Task/new.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui/DatePicker' in

Comment: run the command in root folder ' npm install --save material-ui ' then import ' import DatePicker from 'material-ui/DatePicker'; ' in the component where you want to use DatePicker

Comment: I want use NEXT branch!!! My question about NEXT branch
npm install --save material-ui@next '

Comment: https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/getting-started/supported-components not yet supported